# jQuery Slider with Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm trying to create a slider that should be relatively easy, but I'm unsure if I have to build it out manually or if there is an existing script I could use for it.

The slider design can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0R8W.jpg).

I'm thinking I could use a fade in / fade out effect for the text and photo at the top, and then add  / remove an active class for the "tabs" underneath.

Is there a suggestion as to a pre-made script that I could use or do I have no choice but to do it manually?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you just thinking outloud, or do you have a question?

Comment: also the slider they are using is here http://bxslider.com/

Comment: Oops! I meant to ask "Is there a suggestion as to a pre-made script that I could use or do I have no choice but to do it manually?" -- I'm going to check out BXSlider now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written some days ago a quite simple solution, take a look: http://cssdeck.com/labs/tabs

```
var menu = $('.menu'),
    tabs = menu.find('a'),
    panes = $('.tab_pane');

tabs.on('click', function() {
    var elem = $(this);

    if (!elem.hasClass('active')) {
        panes.stop(true, true).slideUp();
        tabs.removeClass('active');
        $(panes[elem.parent().index()]).slideDown();
        elem.addClass('active');
    }

});
```